# How to calculate volume of a bathymetry, excluding the land data

Tags: matlab, volume

I have plotted my bathymetry in a gridded form. Since I was new to stackoverflow and I was not allowed to attach image with my post, I could only mail you the image. I have calculated the volume of bathymetry using:

```
dx * dy * zi(~isnan(zi))
```

However, that also includes the land data (i.e. area that falls below the coastline). Now, I need help to remove the land data that falls below the coastline from the bathymetry before I can calculate the volume.

I don't know how to define in MATLAB that I want to remove whatever data that falls below the coastline.

Comment: You need to show some more code.

Comment: You can also upload the image to a third-party site and put the link here - somebody may edit it in for you.